# Laravel/Intervention: Image source not readable

Tags: php, laravel, image, intervention

I am trying to create an image within my laravel 8 project using the intervention image library.
There I installed intervention via composer and tried to run the example code given on the intervention website within a models function:

```
private function draw()
{
   $img = Image::make('foo.jpg')->resize(300, 200);
}
```

However, when I am running this part of code, I receive the error
**Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException: Image source not readable**.

When I am googleing for that problem, I found lots of people, who had that kind of error, because the laravel symlink from "public/storage/" to "storage/app/public" was missing (php artisan storage:link). However, this is not the case for me, as the linking works properly.

Does anyone have an idea what else I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the foo.jpg image is in the right place, in the public folder in this example?

Comment: @zlatan You're right, I expected that the public/storage path ist the default path. However, it is the public folder. When changing the code to Image::make('storage/foo.jpg')->resize(300, 200) it works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help.